# How can I get the unicode values of Bullets in a word document

Tags: python, regex, ms-word

I am working on a web application and don't want user to input some invalid characters which are creating problems.

One such character which is causing problem is **diamond bullet** from MS word but to remove that character I need to know the Unicode of the character so that I could include it in the Python regular expression of invalid characters [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698267/efficient-way-to-search-for-invalid-characters-in-python).

```
textString = some value which need to be checked for invalid characters
pattern = some regular expression for invalid characters
if pattern.search(textString):
    print 'Invalid characters found'
else:
    print 'Valid string'
```

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399244/view-the-character-unicode-values-of-a-word-document#) but this is not working for bullets.

Guys please help me resolving this issue.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "unicode bullet"?

Comment: @mvm, I tried! I found U+2022

Comment: @Plasma I also found this but do I need to search for Unicode value of that particular bullet?

Comment: Guys can you please give me hint if you know rather than down voting

Comment: If you know which characters you don't want to allow (or conversely, the only ones you want to allow), one approach could be to use a regex on unicode ranges. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748855/how-do-i-specify-a-range-of-unicode-characters-in-a-regular-expression-in-python) answer on how to work with unicode ranges. Edit: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698267/efficient-way-to-search-for-invalid-characters-in-python?lq=1) is a discussion on a general approach.

Comment: @Plasma Yes, of course you are correct in pointing it out but my problem is knowing Unicode of a particular character i.e. diamond bullet in MS Word. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You should lookup tables of unicode characters. [This one of geometric shapes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/list.htm) contain some diamonds, at least

Comment: Also, fileformat.info has a unicode character [search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) to identify unicode values.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Word document with your invalid characters.  (Don't use the bullet maker icon, use the Insert->symbol->symbol browser and pick it from the map).

Unzip it.

```
unzip myDoc.docx
```

and open the word/document.xml file in an editor capable of reading the unicode characters.  Here I am using **xmllint** and **more** as a quick and dirty example.  I don't know which bullet you are talking about, but the one I tried here shows U+F075:

```
xmllint --format word/document.xml | more

<w:r w:rsidR="00A50B17" w:rsidRPr="00E62AD7">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Wingdings" w:hAnsi="Wingdings"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t><U+F075></w:t>
  </w:r>
```

Then for all the unicode characters, put them in your script.